# I have n number of elemet in the 2 sets and i have to go through them such that at each iteration i get the current element ans also the next element

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, set

BELOW , Is the code i wrote which is showing error ( that we cant use end()-1 and itr+1 operations).
MY purpose is to go through the set as in pair. eg X[1 2 3] i want to get {1 2} {2 3}.

```
    for(itr=X.begin();itr!=X.end()-1;itr++) 
    {
        int l1,l2;
        l1 = *(itr+1) - *itr;
        for(itr1=Y.begin();itr1!=Y.end()+1;itr1++)
        {

            l2 = *(itr1+1) - *itr1;
            
            int l = min(l1,l2);
            int num = (l*l)/(a*a);
            
            count += num;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, provide whole code, I don't understand what are you trying to achieve with your computations, when you stated that you just want to iterate array to get pairs.

Comment: In the title you say `set` in the question you say `array`, which is it? Assuming you really did mean set see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set iterators don't support `+` or `-`. This seems like the easiest way to do what you want

```
std::set<int> X = ...;
auto i = X.begin();
if (i != X.end())
{
    auto j = ++i;
    while (j != X.end())
    {
        int l1 = *j - *i;
        ...
        // similar code for Y loop
        ...
        ++i;
        ++j;
    }
}
```

It basically the same as your code but it uses two adjacent iterators `i` and `j` in one loop to avoid having to use `+` and `-`.

Comment: I was about to say, why not just use two iterators, when you posted your answer.

Comment: yeah , i was trying to do the same , but can i use end()-- instead of end()-1 and same with itr in my above code , will it work. but thanx for the answer , it is what i was looking for .